# Wordpress return specific keys and values from serialized string in database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, serialization

I'm busy attempting to pull particular data from a serialized string in the WP database. The raw string looks like this:

```
{"params":{"1":{"key":"1","enabled":"1","value":"Yes"},"2":{"key":"2","enabled":"1","value":"No"}}}
```

I am able to (apparently) retrieve this string with the following code:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT options FROM wp_wpl_dbst WHERE table_column = '{$id}'");
$parseme = unserialize($results);
```

However, I am unable to actually pull any values from the array I've apparently just created.

I tried some variations of the following code, all of which result in the same error:

```
foreach ($parseme as $parsed) {
    $return_string .= $parsed['key'] . '<br>';
    $return_string .= $parsed['value'] . '<br>';
}
```

The error is:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/www/users/.../functions.php on line 236

Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: That looks like JSON, not a serialized string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw string you're showing isn't a serialized string. A serialized string has key lengths in it and looks like this: `a:2:{i:0;s:4:"test";i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:4:"test";i:1;R:3;}}`. What you're retrieving is actually `JSON`.

So you should be able to replace `unserialize($results)` with `json_decode( $results, true )` and then you'll have access to an associative array. Note that you still have an outer array with the `params` key. Take the below code for example

```
$results       = '{"params":{"1":{"key":"1","enabled":"1","value":"Yes"},"2":{"key":"2","enabled":"1","value":"No"}}}';
$results_array = json_decode( $results, true );
$return        = '';

foreach( $results_array['params'] as $array ){
    $return .= $array['key'].'<br>';
    $return .= $array['value'].'<br>';  
}
```

This will output the following:

```
string(23) "1
Yes
2
No
"
```

Comment: Works perfectly now, thanks. Not sure where I went wrong because I suspected it was JSON at first as well, but couldn't get that working either.

Answer (score 0):

The String is JSON

```
{"params":{"1":{"key":"1","enabled":"1","value":"Yes"},"2":{"key":"2","enabled":"1","value":"No"}}}
```

We can use json_decode to cover into the object, try this

```
$results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT options FROM wp_wpl_dbst WHERE table_column = '{$id}'");
$parseme = json_decode($results);
```